# Error when compiling pdf using knitr in rstudio

Tags: r, knitr, sweave, rstudio

I have installed the packages *Sweave* as well as *knitr* on both Linux mint and Windows 7, and it works well on Windows, **but fails when using rstudio in Linux**. After installing the pkgs, I write a simple *dw.Rnw* as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

The regression model is as follows
<<echo=TRUE>>=
pop=read.table("pop.txt",header=TRUE)
attach(pop)

lm.sol=lm(y~year)
summary(lm.sol)
@


\end{document}
```

When I press the button '*Compile PDF*' in rstudio, it returns the following error messages:

```
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
5: Setting LC_PAPER failed, using "C" 
6: Setting LC_PAPER failed, using "C" 
7: Setting LC_MEASUREMENT failed, using "C" 
> grDevices::pdf.options(useDingbats = FALSE); require(knitr); knit('dw.Rnw', encoding='UTF-8')
Loading required package: knitr
Warning in readLines(if (is.character(input2)) { :
  cannot open file 'dw.Rnw': No such file or directory
Error in readLines(if (is.character(input2)) { : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: knit -> readLines
Execution halted
```

It seems there is something wrong with the function *knit*. However, if I type

```
knit("dw.Rnw")
```

in the console of rstudio, then it successfully generates the file dw.tex, which I can compile with pdflatex and finally generate dw.pdf.

So what's wrong with my knitr or rstudio?

Comment: From the startup warning messages, it looks like you set some wrong environment variables, or screwed something in `~/.Rprofile`. Please post `x=as.list(Sys.getenv());str(x[grep('^L[AC]',names(x))])` and check if there is anything wrong in `~/.Rprofile` (if it exists).

Comment: Thanks a lot Yihui! It seems that there is something wrong with my ~/.Rprofile, since after clearing all settings in it, I can compile pdf with rstudio! Actually I only have the following two settings in .Rprofile:
setwd("~/Rproject")
options(editor="/usr/bin/vim")
Can you tell me what's wrong with my settings? Thanks again.

Comment: I think `setwd()` in .Rprofile is a bad practice, but I do not see how it can affect your R locale.

Comment: You are right. I tested by adding `setwd()` in `.Rprofile.site` on windows, and then there came the same problem. All in all, thank you Yihui!

Comment: Okay, I have written that as the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although I still do not understand why, but from the comments above, the problem seems to come from `~/.Rprofile` (in particular, `setwd()`). Clearing it up solves the problem.

Note you may have other startup profile files. `.Rprofile` is only one possibility. See `?Startup` for more information. For example, if you are on Windows, you may need to take a look at `C:\Program Files\R\etc\Rprofile.site` if it exists.

Comment: just guessing, but this would seem exactly as expected if (1) the separate R session that Rstudio spawns before calling `knitr <filename>` assumes that `<filename>` is in the current working directory; (2) `.Rprofile` gets executed at the beginning of that session; (3) the current working directory is different from `~/Rproject`

Comment: @BenBolker I'm sure the locale was wrong in the original problem. I just do not know why it was screwed up. The working directory should not affect the locale.

Comment: I thought the locale warnings were a separate/unrelated issue

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for your comments. I have also tried setting the current working directory to be the same as that in ~/.Rprofile, but the problem was still there.

Comment: I think you CAN use setwd() in .Rprofile but you have to use `if (interactive()) setwd(<dir>)` At least, this worked for me having a similar error.

Comment: @Yihui, please extend your answer to include the information that the critical setting of the working directory might also be found in `C:\Program Files\R\etc\Rprofile.site`, as @zeno tsang pointed out above. This was causing the problem in my case.

Comment: The information from @swolf should probably be included in an answer.