# Error compiling .Rnw files in RStudio: Issue with project path?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, rnw

When I try to compile a PDF from an `Rnw` file in RStudio, I receive the following error:

> Loading required package: knitr
>
> Error in readLines(if (is.character(input2)) { :
>
> cannot open the connection
>
> Calls: knit -> readLines
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In readLines(if (is.character(input2)) { :
>
> cannot open file 'Rnw_test.Rnw': No such file or directory
>
> Execution halted

This only happens at my office PC, not at home, so I suppose there is no problem with the `Rnw` file itself.

My problem seems to be identical to this one: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826153/error-when-compiling-pdf-using-knitr-in-rstudio#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826153/error-when-compiling-pdf-using-knitr-in-rstudio#_=_). But my Rprofile is unchanged, so this does not help, unfortunately.

Also, running `knitr::knit("file.Rnw")` in the console does not work and throws the same error.

Since Yihui asked for the output of `as.list(Sys.getenv());str(x[grep('^L[AC]',names(x))])` in the thread I mentioned above, here it is:

```
$ALLUSERSPROFILE
[1] "C:\\ProgramData"

$APPDATA
[1] "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming"

$BS
[1] "w7"

$CACHE
[1] "C:\\Cache"

$CommonProgramFiles
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files"

$`CommonProgramFiles(x86)`
[1] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files"

$CommonProgramW6432
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files"

$COMPUTERNAME
[1] "NAME"

$ComSpec
[1] "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"

$DEFLOGDIR
[1] "C:\\ProgramData\\McAfee\\DesktopProtection"

$DISPLAY
[1] ":0"

$FP_NO_HOST_CHECK
[1] "NO"

$GFORTRAN_STDERR_UNIT
[1] "-1"

$GFORTRAN_STDOUT_UNIT
[1] "-1"

$HOME
[1] "//HomedirFiler06.office.in.company.de./homedirs06$/user/Eigene Dateien"

$HOMEDRIVE
[1] "U:"

$HOMEPATH
[1] "\\"

$HOMESHARE
[1] "\\\\HomedirFiler06.office.in.company.de.\\homedirs06$\\user"

$IEVersion
[1] "11"

$KEYFILELOCATION
[1] "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\IBM\\Notes\\Data"

$LG
[1] "de"

$LOCALAPPDATA
[1] "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local"

$LOGONSERVER
[1] "\\\\M913DCRWI102P"

$NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS
[1] "2"

$OS
[1] "Windows_NT"

$PATH
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\R\\bin\\x64;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C    :\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Windows\\idmu\\common;C:\\Windows\\System3    2\\Windows System Resource Manager\\bin;;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\Notes;C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\;C:\\Program     Files\\SAS\\Secure\\ccme4;C:\\Program Files\\SAS\\x86\\Secure\\ccme4;C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\IBM\\Notes\\Data"

$PATHEXT
[1] ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC"

$PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
[1] "AMD64"

$PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER
[1] "Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel"

$PROCESSOR_LEVEL
[1] "6"

$PROCESSOR_REVISION
[1] "3c03"

$ProgramData
[1] "C:\\ProgramData"

$ProgramFiles
[1] "C:\\Program Files"

$`ProgramFiles(x86)`
[1] "C:\\Program Files (x86)"

$ProgramW6432
[1] "C:\\Program Files"

$PSModulePath
[1] "C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules\\"

$PUBLIC
[1] "C:\\Users\\Public"

$R_ARCH
[1] "/x64"

$R_COMPILED_BY
[1] "gcc 4.9.3"

$R_DOC_DIR
[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/doc"

$R_HOME
[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R"

$R_LIBS_USER
[1] "//HomedirFiler06.office.in.company.de./homedirs06$/user/Eigene Dateien/R/win-library/3.3"

$R_USER
[1] "//HomedirFiler06.office.in.company.de./homedirs06$/user/Eigene Dateien"

$RMARKDOWN_MATHJAX_PATH
[1] "C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/mathjax-23"

$RS_LOCAL_PEER
[1] "\\\\.\\pipe\\38725-rsession"

$RS_RPOSTBACK_PATH
[1] "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/rpostback"

$RS_SHARED_SECRET
[1] "63341846741"

$RSTUDIO
[1] "1"

$RSTUDIO_MSYS_SSH
[1] "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/msys-ssh-1000-18"

$RSTUDIO_PANDOC
[1] "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc"

$RSTUDIO_SESSION_PORT
[1] "38725"

$RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY
[1] "user"

$SESSIONNAME
[1] "Console"

$SNC_LIB
[1] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SAP\\FrontEnd\\SecureLogin\\lib\\sapcrypto.dll"

$SNC_LIB_64
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\SAP\\FrontEnd\\SecureLogin\\lib\\sapcrypto.dll"

$SSF_LIBRARY_PATH
[1] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SAP\\FrontEnd\\SecureLogin\\lib\\sapcrypto.dll"

$SSF_LIBRARY_PATH_64
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\SAP\\FrontEnd\\SecureLogin\\lib\\sapcrypto.dll"

$SystemDrive
[1] "C:"

$SystemRoot
[1] "C:\\Windows"

$TEMP
[1] "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"

$TMP
[1] "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"

$UATDATA
[1] "C:\\Windows\\CCM\\UATData\\D9F8C395-CAB8-491d-B8AC-179A1FE1BE77"

$UEM_BV
[1] "870"

$USERDNSDOMAIN
[1] "IN.company.DE"

$USERDOMAIN
[1] "IN"

$USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE
[1] "IN"

$USERNAME
[1] "user"

$USERPROFILE
[1] "C:\\Users\\user"

$VSEDEFLOGDIR
[1] "C:\\ProgramData\\McAfee\\DesktopProtection"

$windir
[1] "C:\\Windows"

$windows_tracing_flags
[1] "3"

$windows_tracing_logfile
[1] "C:\\BVTBin\\Tests\\installpackage\\csilogfile.log"

$officerFlexBackupSpeicher
[1] "\\\\profilserver03.in.company.de\\profile_backup$\\user"

$officerFlexSpeicher
[1] "\\\\profilserver02.in.company.de\\profile_flex$\\user"
```

And here my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252 LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5  tools_3.3.3   stringi_1.0-1 knitr_1.15.1  stringr_1.1.0 evaluate_0.10
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

**Edit: Details on compilation**

I started the compilation via the *Compile PDF* Button in RStudio as well as via `knitr::knit("file.Rnw")` in the R Console.

Thanks to Yihui's hint I figured that the working directory of the project was not the folder where the `.Rproj` file is located but one level above. Taking this into account I can compile the file via the R Console.

But how can I fix this such that I can use the *Compile PDF* Button?

Comment: How exactly did you compile your Rnw document? Command line? The Knit button in RStudio? What is your working directory? Are you sure the file exists under your working directory?

Comment: Thanks @Yihui for your comment. In fact, the file is not in the folder (I feel somewhat dumb about this). More specifically, the working directory of the project is not the folder in which the `.Rproj` file is located, but one level above. From what I understand, this is not the normal behaviour. How can this be fixed?

I also edited my initial question to include this issue.

Comment: The Compile PDF button should work no matter what your working directory is, but `knitr::knit()` definitely requires the file you pass to it exists.

Comment: Since manually using `knit` in the console (with the correct path ;) ) does work, I conclude that there is no problem with `knitr` (I use version 1.16). 

I tried the _Compile PDF_ button from within another project as well as without any project; both resulted in the error message shown in my question.

I use RStudio version 1.0.44 with R 3.3.3.

Comment: I finally got the information from my colleage that there was a function `.First` in the file `C:\Program Files\R\etc\Rprofile.site` which was setting the working directory to `U:\Eigene Dateien\R`.  
Removing the corresponding line and restarting R fixed my problem.  
Thus, this is a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826153/error-when-compiling-pdf-using-knitr-in-rstudio#=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826153/error-when-compiling-pdf-using-knitr-in-rstudio#=), if you slightly adapt your answer to the other question.